# Android application crashes when trying to get string length

Tags: java, android, string

Those who invented Android and Java didn't invented for themselves. Since I started developing application with Java in Android I get the most ridiculous errors and I am really going crazy (and if I do, Google and Sun Microsystems will make "booooom")

I have this simple code that is supposed to get the length of a string passed as an argument. The application just crashes, making me spend some minutes swearing and torturing the keyboard.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result.length() == 0) {
        txtStatus.setText("Ready");
    }
}
```

If I remove the condition it works (the text "Ready" is shown on my TextView). This is something weird and I know that I might be missing some little something.

Give me some clues and thanks for everything!

*P.S. If you hear a gun shoot coming from your neighbor it might be me.*

Comment: Save yourself a lot of stress and learn about the logcat utility - available through Eclipse or from the command line. When something crashes the logcat output will include a stack trace which has useful hints such as null pointer exception. In the worst case copy/paste the exception message into a Google search to find others who have seen the same problem and gain from the wisdom of others who have already solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because your string is perhaps *null*. Do it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
        txtStatus.setText("Ready");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! I initiated result as null but I thought that it would become an empty string after getting an empty content from a web page. Anyway, your answer was my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result != null && result.length() == 0) {
        txtStatus.setText("Ready");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if result is null first, Handle it appropriately, then check it's length. My best guess is you have an unhandled NullPointerException.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result == null) {
        result = ""; // change this line if null is an error.
    }
    if (result.length() == 0) {
        txtStatus.setText("Ready");
    }
}
```

A debugging technique to figure out what is wrong and making your program crash would be to wrap the condition in a try/catch block.

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        if (result.length() == 0) {
            txtStatus.setText("Ready");
        }
    catch (Throwable t) { // both error and exception inherit from Throwable.
        // print or inspect 't' here to determine the reason for the crash.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by Waqas the problem is because your string maybe null. If the string is null the method length is not defined.So add an additional condition checking for null i.e

```
if(result ==NULL)
// do something else
else
//your code here
```